# cout giving Runtime Error

Tags: c++

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n=100000;
    int cost=6;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        cout<<cost<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above program when compiled and run on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com) (online g++ compiler which uses SPOJ compiler) gives a Runtime Error. When the `cout` line is commented out, the program runs successfully. Can someone point out the reason for the same?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code (other than it should be `<iostream>`).

Comment: Maybe there is a limit at ideone.com on the maximum number of bytes your program is allowed to print. Change n to something smaller (10000, 1000, 100 or 10) and see if your problem is solved.

Comment: It worked fine for me on http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php

Comment: It is always a good idea to add the error message to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pts pointed it out in his comment, ideone.com has a limit to the number of bytes you can print out. If you change n to 10000, the code runs fine.

The maximum n value that won't give compile error is 2^15 = 32768.

If you look carefully, you can see it terminates with signal:25, SIGXFSZ. You can take a look at [this page](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++Signals.html) to learn what signals mean.

> SIGXFSZ   25  File size limit exceeded (4.2 BSD)

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically this could overflow if `int` is two bytes on your platform (which the standard allows). But most likely the error is due to output size limits at `ideone.com`. Do learn to interpret error messages: they are your friends and are as least as important as desired program output.